# How do you store a tuple in a geopandas geodataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have

```
blocks["centroid"] = blocks.centroid
```

doing that will store a `shapely.Point` in `blocks["centroid"]` but the `shp` format does not accept two geometries at the time of `blocks.to_file()`. So I'm trying to save the values as, maybe a tuple or a list, but merely doing

```
blocks["centroid"] = (blocks.centroid.x, blocks.centroid.y)
```

won't work, throwing.

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

how should I store the lat/lon of the point in a **single** column?

Comment: maybe `blocks['centroid'] = list(zip(blocks.centroid.x, blocks.centroid.y))`?

Comment: [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) might help too:  `blocks.centroid.x.astype(str).str.cat(blocks.centroid.y.astype(str), sep=', ')`

Comment: `(blocks.centroid.x, blocks.centroid.y)` is a tuple of two arrays, not an array of tuples

Comment: Given that a Shapefile also doesn't support a list or tuple as values in a column, and storing it as a string is a bit awkward, another option is to store the x and y coordinates it as two separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you store a tuple in a geopandas geodataframe?

```py
blocks['centroid'] = blocks.apply(
    lambda row: (row['geometry'].centroid.x,
                 row['geometry'].centroid.y), axis=1)
```

results:

```
> blocks['centroid']
0       (3.74932619950664, -3.54174728953859)
1      (3.83665124133256, -3.556156891148994)
..
```

but this will not let you use `.to_file()` to save as ESRI Shapefile. Because ESRI Shapefile does not support `tuple` nor `list`.

> how should I store the lat/lon of the point in a single column **and save it as ESRI Shapefile**?

ESRI Shapefile supports these [types](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm) only. We can save the centroid coordinates as a concatenated string.

```py
blocks['centroid'] = blocks.apply(
    lambda row: '{},{}'.format(row['geometry'].centroid.x,
                               row['geometry'].centroid.y), axis=1)

blocks.to_file(filename='blocks', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

results

```
> blocks['centroid']
0       3.74932619950664,-3.54174728953859
1      3.83665124133256,-3.556156891148994
..
```